# Python, Simulate Question Answer with a certain probability

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which I have the probability of committing an action similar to this one:

```
Diz = {'A' = 0.5,
    'B' = 0.2,
    'C' = 0.3,
    'A|B' = 0.95,
    'B|A' = 0.2,
}
```

I have a List of Action

```
L = [A,B,C]
```

I want to simulate the probability of answering a question:
For example I have
Question A:
I want that out of then trial the answer will be correct for 50% of the time and
the rest-ant 50 % will be not correct. Same for the other variables.

For example if I run ten times the algorithm 10 times the result should be deterministic with respect to the probability:

```
A = Corr,
A = Non-Corr
A = Corr,
A = Non-Corr
A = Corr,
A = Non-Corr
A = Corr,
A = Non-Corr
A = Corr,
A = Non-Corr
```

Similar for the other variables.

Comment: One way would be to just have a list of 10 values, 5 'A's , 2 'B's and 3 'C's. When you randomly select from this list, you would end up honoring the probabilities of 0.5, 0.3 and 0.2 respectively, I'm not sure I understand what A|B and B|A means though.

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar Yep you right, this is what I was thinking. A|B and B|A is the conditonal proabability, so I am supposing that the variable are corralated.